# CursorAdapter bindView and newView not firing

Tags: java, android, android-cursoradapter

So I am trying to get my information from a database and return it into a custom formatted ListView which I have already created.

from my **MainActivity.java** I am launching my **history.java** file which should display all the data!

**history.java** looks as follows

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.history);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Roboto-Light.ttf");

        ListView listContent = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        TextView history = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.history);
        history.setTypeface(tf);

        MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

        Cursor cursor = db.getAllLogs();
        Log.d("history.java", "finished Cursor cursor = db.getAllLogs();");
        GasCursorAdapter adapter = new GasCursorAdapter(this, cursor, 0);
        Log.d("history.java", "GasCursorAdapter adapter = new GasCursorAdapter(this, cursor, 0);");
        listContent.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.d("history.java", "setAdapter(adapter);");
        cursor.close();
    }

}
```

(in the log I am seeing everything here fire - good!)

here is my **MySQLiteHelper.java** which I am using to get all the data.

```
public Cursor getAllLogs() {
        List<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_GASLOG;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        Log.d("MySQLiteHelper.java", "through getAllLogs()");
        return cursor;
        }
```

(I am seeing the log there as well - good!)

and here is my **GasCursorAdapter.java**

```
public class GasCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {


    //private LayoutInflater mInflater = null;

    public GasCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags){
        super(context, c, flags);
        //mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Log.d("inGasCursorAdapter", "GasCursorAdapter");
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_background, parent, false);
        Log.d("inGasCursorAdapter", "newView");
        return retView;
        //return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_background,  parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor cursor){
        TextView cardDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardDate);
        int date = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_DATE);
        cardDate.setText(date);
        TextView cardGallons = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardGallons);
        cardGallons.setText((int) cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(3))));
        Log.d("inGasCursorAdapter", "through bindView");
    }

}
```

I am seeing it get through the first method, but the newView and bindView method are never firing.  I think because of this, my history.java page just comes back blank, no data is showing :(

Any ideas as to what I might have out of order or be missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked how many rows you have in your `Cursor`? It will not show anything if it is empty.

Comment: i did a Log for cursor and i get the following:

01-30 12:51:29.533: D/cursor(21492): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41f450d0

not sure if that is the correct way to check or not?

Comment: No, `cursor.getCount()` gives you the number of rows.

Comment: You be opening your database too. You declare it but never call `db.open()`. Running the `cursor.getCount()` will show you zero because its not writing in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the data containing cursor into `GasCursorAdapter` constructor try to use `swapCursor` method of your adapter after attaching it to the `ListView`. Anyway, the better way is to use the [`CursorLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) class because it provides you loading from data source outside UI thread. Yeah, you should implement your own `ContentProvider` for this, but you can just extend the `AsyncTaskLoader` class and implement there direct retrieving data using `MySQLiteHelper`